# Responsiveness not working for sliders

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, responsive-slides

I have tried making the sliders responsive but it is not working for me.

Out of the 3 sliders, the main slider has been made responsive. But the other two sliders is not able to make responsive.

This [link](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://www.codeigniter.in/projects/astha/index.php) will give you a clear picture of my problem:

You can scroll through **iPhone 3+4 portrait · width: 320px** to see my exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
.spotlightslider {
   width: 100%;
}
```

inside

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 470px) and (min-width: 310px)
```

Comment: That helped me to solve the issue associated with Spotlightslider. Could you please help me resolve the issue with the slider having quotes ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which one are you referring about. They all look good to me. Can you paste some text so that I can search for it?